# How do I get the critical value in statistical hypothesis testing?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

What I am trying to do is to get the value of $\chi^2$ for given probability (let us say $\alpha$=0.01) and degrees of freedom (for example df=3).

How do I get that?

Inverse...Distribution functions return something quite different from expected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, `Quantile[]`? `InverseCDF[]`? `InverseSurvivalFunction[]`? You've seen them? Could you elaborate on "something quite different from expected." with a concrete example?

Comment: @J.M. : Please write your comment as an answer so I could vote it. InverseCDF solves the issue. When used InverseChiSquareDistribution i got values different from expected (as those taken from statistical book tables for Chi square test)

Comment: Tsk, tsk. If you read the docs for `InverseChiSquareDistribution[]`, it's the distribution followed by the reciprocal of a $\chi^2$-distributed variate...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`InverseSurvivalFunction[]` is the nearest to what you want; for a given confidence level $\alpha$ and degree of freedom $\nu$, `InverseSurvivalFunction[ChiSquareDistribution[ν], α]` gives the result you want. Alternatives include `InverseCDF[ChiSquareDistribution[ν], 1 - α]` and `Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[ν], 1 - α]`.